# Displacement map changes when resizing model

Tags: subdivision-surface, shader-nodes, displacement

I have this model of a salamander that works fine in the given dimensions. However, I want to use the salamander in a different scene where I need to scale the model down by 0.1. By doing so, I lose a lot of detail and the skin surface of the salamander becomes too flat and smooth. However, I want to keep the displacements exactly as they are in the 10 times larger model. I am looking for a solution where the model stays exactly the same no matter what the size.

I have already tried

- applying the subdivision surface, which doesn't make a difference.
  -Set the object space to world space in the displacement node, which has an effect but gives me some weird results.
- Add some extra subdivisions to the mesh, which somehow makes it better, but still looks different from the 10 times larger model.

Since I am using a displacement map,

- the feature set is set to experimental
- the model has a subdivision surface (simple)
- the material settings are set to "displacement and pump".

Thanks for your help

[image: Original size]

[image: 10x smaller size]

[image: Node Setup]

[image: Blender]